# Error when trying to load require module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I've been trying to understand how to set up Stripe for my app but am having problems with the implementation of the module. Normally when using a module i would require it in the top of the file to be able to use it but when i do it in the paymentCtrl file it doesn't work and i get the two errors below: where am i supposed to declare it for me to be able to use it? Well as you see i'm quite new to this and would like to understand how to structure this so that the payments work.

errors:

> Unexpected token.

and

> Failed to instantiate module paymentController due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'paymentController' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

paymentCtrl:

```
angular.module('paymentController', [])

var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_....');


.controller('paymentCtrl', function($scope) {


});
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('userApp', ['appRoutes', 'userControllers', 'userServices', 'ngAnimate', 'mainController', 'authServices', 'managementController', 'paymentController'])

.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptors');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to move line:

```
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_....');
```

above line:

```
angular.module('paymentController', [])
```

Comment: Then i get the error:

require is not defined
    at paymentCtrl.js:1

Comment: I believe require is for the server side.  You need to load  'stripe' library in front end.  Using bower, webpack, or <script></script> in your html should work.